# Boolean Modifier is merging weirdly

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I've been wanting to cut out a specific shape of my objects, but anytime i use the Boolean modifier it merges the two objects. Here's a list of things i already tried/fixed:

- All the normals are facing the same way
- My objects are watertight
- I removed all the double vertices
- i switched the solver between fast and exact
- i split my objects into smaller parts
- And yes i have already tried scaling my object on the Z axis so that it's taller than the other object

Here's a picture of what it does instead of difference them:
[image]

And here's what the seperate objects look like:[image]

[image]

Comment: Try scaling your boolean object on the Z axis so that there's a reasonable overlap between that and the 'road' object then Ctrl-A > Scale on both objects in Object mode and see what happens. If that doesn't fix it we'll need to see your blend file as James says below.

Comment: i've already tried scaling it so that it goes through the whole thing but sadly didnt help much, my file is also now added. i appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

If this is what you are looking for, activate the *Exact* solver with the *Hole Tolerant* option:

[image: Cut]

Comment: I always forget that option as it's normally hidden! Yes. That will work.

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! i cant believe it was such a simple thing all along haha. i was really getting frustrated because i tried finding out the issue for hours